# What is the purpose of spring model addObject(Object attributeName)?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

In spring mvc, when creating a ModelAndView there's a method called `addObject(Object attributeName)` single parameter, and I don't understand how to make use of it. I also see `model.addAllObjects(Map<String, ?> object)`.

How can I get that map in jsp? Or what is the purpose of those methods? I only know how to make use of `model.addObject("car", new Car())` because is like defining servlet parameters. I found this information in spring but I don't really understand it.

[Spring addObject and addAllObjects](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html#addObject-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: Note that it's not "addObject(Object attributeName)", but ["addObject(Object attribute*Value*)"](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html#addObject-java.lang.Object-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

please check the example below. i have shed how to use `addObject(Object attributeValue)` as well as `addAllObjects(Map<String, ?> modelMap)`.

**Car.java**

```
public class Car {

    private String regNo;
    private String model;
    private String year;
    public String getRegNo() {
        return regNo;
    }
    public void setRegNo(String regNo) {
        this.regNo = regNo;
    }
    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }
    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }
    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
}
```

**PageContent.java**

```
public class PageContent {

    private String headerName;

    public String getHeaderName() {
        return headerName;
    }

    public void setHeaderName(String headerName) {
        this.headerName = headerName;
    }
}
```

**Controller Method**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/showCars", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showApp() {

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();

    //adding a single attribute for the modelMap
    PageContent pageContent = new PageContent();
    pageContent.setHeaderName("All Cars - From Controller");
    modelAndView.addObject(pageContent);

    List<Car> carList = new ArrayList<>();

    Car car1 = new Car();
    car1.setModel("Toyota");
    car1.setRegNo("223456");
    car1.setYear("2005");

    Car car2 = new Car();
    car2.setModel("Mazda");
    car2.setRegNo("24244");
    car2.setYear("2015");

    Car car3 = new Car();
    car3.setModel("Nissan");
    car3.setRegNo("4465757");
    car3.setYear("2013");

    carList.add(car1);
    carList.add(car2);
    carList.add(car3);

    Map<String,Object> allObjectsMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    allObjectsMap.put("allCarObjects", carList);

    //adding a set of objects for the model map
    modelAndView.addAllObjects(allObjectsMap);

    modelAndView.setViewName("CarView");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

**CarView.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>

    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>ModelAttribute Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>${pageContent.headerName}</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Model</th>
                <th>Registration No</th>
                <th>Year of Manufacture</th>
            </tr>

            <c:forEach var="car" items="${allCarObjects}">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${car.model}" /></td>

                    <td><c:out value="${car.regNo}" /></td>

                    <td><c:out value="${car.year}" /></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Hope this will helpful for you!

Comment: Thank you. It's a nice explanation

Answer (score 0):

well,the first method addObject which would invoked when forward happend and brings the data to jsp.Then you can iterate the data in your jsp with jstl or something else.The method addAllObjects is just a multiple type of addObject,just like map's method put and putAll.

Comment: Could you please show me an example? with addObject("mylist", carsList) I reffer to that list in jsp with foreach var="car" items="mylist". How can I reffer an object that is added with addAllObjects(Map...) in jsp to iterate through? Thanks

Comment: `public ModelAndView addAllObjects(java.util.Map<String, ?> modelMap)`,if you know the ModelMap(I think it as part of ModelAndView),you will understand.Well,iterate it in jsp just like the list but a little diferent.